# Weird black shade in my normal map model

Tags: texture-baking

[image][image]

I'm using cycles, did uv on both meshes. No idea what is this. Yes this is showing in cycles as well....

Comment: I don't really see the issue in your render, but read this : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/normal_map.html and make sure your image texture node is set to Non-Color. Your normal image texture looks good to me.

Comment: Putted another picture for you to see. My image is already set to non color.

Comment: Can you send .blend file? Make sure it's packed so I get the texture. Could be intersecting object, or modifiers, it's really hard to tell from this 2 screenshots.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eDMcYwwnFx46L8lhkolczP7yMTfesrgf

Comment: You are pushing the normals too hard, above 1 strength anything can happen in term of artifacts. At 1 there is no glitchs whatsoever.

Comment: I was using strenght to make them more visible. I tried displacement as well but it doesnt looks good. I want them to pop out more you know.

Comment: @Arthur blaquart, this bug was fixed on blender 2.80, or so the blender webite says.